# Producer/Consumer_problem (Semaphores)

Tags: c++, linux, fork, semaphore

So I've got task to solve producer-consumer problem using semaphores. I must have FIFO buffer and option to  push/pop the same item several times in a row.
I should test it using fork() function to create a new process.
The problem is that when I try to consume an item it stuck on wait() function

There is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <mutex>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

using namespace std;


mutex wrt,rd,ks;
int buffer[100];
sem_t sem_in,sem_out;
int n, lo, hi;

void produce(int repeat)
{
    cout<<"IN produce after paramiters"<< repeat <<endl;
    int item;
    item = rand()%100 + 1;
    wrt.lock();
    ks.lock();
            for(int i=0; i<repeat; i++)
            {
                if(n != 100){sem_wait(&sem_in);}
                else{ks.unlock(); sem_wait(&sem_in); ks.lock();}
                buffer[hi] = item;
                hi = (hi + 1) % 100;        //ring buffer
                n = n +1;         //one more item in buffer
                cout<< "Item: "<< item << " Was prodused n = " << n << endl;
                sem_post(&sem_out);
            }
    ks.unlock();
    wrt.unlock();

}

void consume(int repeat)
    {
        cout<<"IN consume after paramiters"<< repeat <<endl;
        rd.lock();
        ks.lock();
            for(int i=0; i<repeat; i++)
            {
                if(n != 0){sem_wait(&sem_out);}
                else{ks.unlock(); sem_wait(&sem_out); ks.lock();}
                int val;
                val = buffer[lo];
                lo = (lo + 1) % 100;
                n -= 1;
                cout<< "Item: "<< val << " Was removed n = " << n << endl;
                sem_post(&sem_in);
            }
        ks.unlock();
        rd.unlock();
    }

int main()
{
    n = 0;
    lo = 0;
    hi = 0;
    srand(time(0));
      pid_t pid;
  int rv = 5;
  sem_init(&sem_in,0,100);
  sem_init(&sem_out,0,0);
  int repeat;
  pid = clone(sem_in,sem_out, n, lo, hi);
  switch(pid) {
  case -1:
          perror("fork"); 
          exit(1); 
  case 0:
          printf(" CHILD: PID -- %d\n", getpid());
          printf(" CHILD: PID parent -- %d\n", getppid());
          repeat = rand()%200 + 1;
          consume(repeat);
          exit(rv);
  default:
          printf("PARENT: PID -- %d\n", getpid());
          printf("PARENT: PID child %d\n",pid);
          repeat = rand()%200 + 1;
          produce(repeat);
          wait();
  }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, please format your code, it's a nuisance to read it as it is, and you do want people to read it, or? Now, what you might be stumbling over is the fact that `fork()` creates a new process with a separate (!) memory space. The global variable `n` in one process has nothing to do with a global variable `n` in a different process. Another question that comes up is why you don't simply use C++ threads, it should be trivial to find example code for a producer-consumer scenario for those.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.